# Kohonen self organizing maps: determining the number of neurons and grid size

Tags: machine-learning, references, neural-networks, self-organizing-maps

I have a large dataset I am trying to do cluster analysis using SOM. The dataset is huge (~ billions of records) and I am not sure what the number of neurons should be or the SOM grid size to start with.

Any pointers to some material that talks about estimating the number of neurons and grid size would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Kohonen's *Self Organizing Maps* (1995) says that the SOM is an approximation of some density function, p(x) and the dimensions for the array should correspond to this distribution.  "*Therefore visual inspection of the rough form of p(x), e.g. by [Sammon's mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sammon_mapping) ought to be done first.*"  p.112

Answer (score 0):

This is my heuristics:

Look at eigenvalues resulted from SVD and watch for relatively large values. Use number of units as the number of higher eigenvalues.

For grid size, take the ratio of largest eigenvalue to second and use that ratio to decide proportion of the map heigh and width